# Codeblock won't run my program, I get sh: filepath: Permission Denied Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, permission-denied

So I'm trying to get this program to run, but code blocks throws me this error when I try to run it.

sh: : Permission Denied.

I'm pretty much 100% noob, so links to figure out how to fix it or educational stuff on the issue would be great for learning I think, but any ideas would be helpful really. :)

Comment: Where is your code located? in some child folder of `/home/<usrname>/`, or is it on another partition? i.e. `/medida/<somepartition>/code/main.cpp`

Comment: `/homer/` interesting.. mine is `/bart/` .. :D

Comment: and btw i had a typo up above as well... should be `/media/<somepartition>/code/main.cpp`

Comment: well the only thing i can think is to go back and make sure you created the correct kind of project (Console Application) likely..

Comment: All right, so my noobness shows that I didn't even create a project. Now that that's taken care of it works.

Comment: well haha it looks like my next general guess was correct by luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correctly set up a project in code::blocks.  (I will walk you through setting up a simple Console Application)

Frist Select "Console Application"

Then Select C or C++

Then Set your project Title and location

And then select the default compiler (GNU GCC Compiler)

Finally some template "hello world" code should appear, press F9 to compile and run.

For other future examples Just check out the Code::Blocks User manual: http://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual or Google

**note** This came from our conversation where we discovered he misc-onfigured Code::Blocks

Comment: It works if I put the project on ubuntu, but if I want the project on my usb it gives permission denied. I need it to work at school too on windows pcs. please help!

Answer (score 3):

If it's an imported project (or you just copied/downloaded it to your hard drive) try rebuilding it.

Start `Codeblocks IDE` => Open the project => Right click => `Rebuild` => Click 'Yes' on the prompt.

This happens every time I copy my old projects from `USB` to `HDD` after clean system install or system update.

I hope this is the case with you as well, because I tried a lot of 'permission related' 
solutions first time I encountered this and they didn't get me far.

Best of luck and I'm looking forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what OS you're using.. but if it's Ubuntu, I use CodeBlocks on Ubuntu and have had this exact problem MANY times.

The "user" option (in etc/fstab) by default sets up "noexec".

so in /etc/fstab just add ,exec after user. i.e. mine looks like this:
`/dev/sda6 /media/DATA vfat uid=kenny,gid=kenny,users,user,exec 0 0`
Though, the spacingis a bit off... but you get the idea.

This may be a bit tough if you're new to linux. So google about the fstab file.
Also, make back up before you try to edit anything (`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup`)

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab` will open up the fstab file so you can see if the filesystem has `exec` in it

Comment: So I looked into it, I don't have this line you're talking about uid=kenny,gid=kenny,users,user,exec 0 0 

On the articles i read about it, all of theirs look more like mine, Which is like this proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

I found the noexec you said, but it was followed with something different and I want to make sure this is correct line before I edit it. Also, It didn't have many of the entries you listed such as users, user stuff like that.

Comment: Also as stated above it was Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: copy yours exactly as is. if its `, noexec 0 0` just change it to `exec 0 0`

Comment: I got 

proc /proc proc nodev,noexec,nosuid 0 0

So I guess the big thing is that I got nosuid after mine?

Comment: I really don't know. But back up your fstab file (like i said above) and change noexec to exec. Save the file, and restart.

Comment: Oh and if we break it i'll give you my IM info and we'll fix it :)

Comment: It didn't break, but it also didn't fix the problem, same problem as before.

Comment: yeah.. i'm not surprised as i have the same settings as you. for mounting the primary partition.. but that was what did the trick for me on other partitions that I tried executing code from..

Comment: so what happens if you just type `g++ main.cpp` then `./a.out`. does the`./a.out` error? (i'm assuming your just trying to get one simple file, like "main.cpp" running)

Comment: Then the only thing i can guess is that you set your project up wrong. create a new project(Console Application) then press F9 and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked the **Abort** button adjacent to Build and Run and it gave this error

> permission denied

I solved the problem by going to Build > Select Target > Release

Answer (score 1):

it may be because the directory/file is not given execute permission you can fix this by using  command on terminal
sudo chmod +x [path to your directory or path to individual file]

like in my case all my codes are in /home/nikhil/code
so
sudo chmod +x /home/nikhil/code

it worked in my case